# Options Checkbox as dropdown in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, css, opencart

This question is about Opencart 2.3.x Options. I have a lot of options with many choices for select, and most of them is multiselect options. If I'll do it as checkbox it will be a long list of choices, what is very complicated. Is it possible to make Checkbox Option as dropdown? If I right understand I must edit catalog/view/theme/...theme.../template/product/product.tpl

How can I edit this file for checkbox dropdown?

```
    <?php // Product Options ---------------------------------------------- ?>

<?php $tbData->slotStart('product/product.product_options', array('data' => $data)); ?>
<?php if ($options || $recurrings): ?>
<?php if ($tbData['system.product_options']['block_title']): ?>
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h2 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $tbData->slotFilter('product/product_options.filter', $options, array('data' => $data)); ?>
<div class="options panel-body form-horizontal">

  <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>

  <?php // SELECT  ?>
  <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
  <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="form-control">
        <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
          <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
          (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
          <?php } ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php // RADIO  ?>
  <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
  <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?><?php if (isset($option['tb_css_classes']) && !empty($option['tb_css_classes'])) echo' tb_' . $option['tb_css_classes']; ?>">
    <?php if ($tbData->OcVersionGte('2.3.0.0') && !empty($option['tb_css_classes']) && $option['tb_css_classes'] == 'style_2' && isset($option['image_width'])): ?>
    <style scoped>
    #input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?> img {
      width: <?php echo $option['image_width']; ?>px;
      height: <?php echo $option['image_height']; ?>px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <div class="radio<?php if (!empty($option_value['image']) && $tbData->OcVersionGte('2.3.0.0')): ?> image<?php endif; ?>">
          <label<?php if (isset($option['tb_css_classes']) && !empty($option['tb_css_classes']) && $option['tb_css_classes'] == 'style_2'): ?> class="tb_bg_str_2 tb_bg_hover_str_3"<?php endif; ?><?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?> title="<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>"<?php } ?>>
            <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
            <?php if ($tbData->OcVersionGte('2.3.0.0')): ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['image']) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /> 
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span>
              <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?><span>
              (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
              </span><?php } ?>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php // CHECKBOX  ?>
  <?php if ($option['type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
  <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?><?php if (isset($option['tb_css_classes']) && !empty($option['tb_css_classes'])) echo' tb_' . $option['tb_css_classes']; ?>">
    <?php if ($tbData->OcVersionGte('2.2.0.0') && !empty($option['tb_css_classes']) && $option['tb_css_classes'] == 'style_2' && isset($option['image_width'])): ?>
    <style scoped>
    #input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?> img {
      width: <?php echo $option['image_width']; ?>px;
      height: <?php echo $option['image_height']; ?>px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <?php if ($tbData->OcVersionGte('2.2.0.0')): ?>
        <div class="checkbox<?php if ($option_value['image']) echo ' image'; ?>">
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="checkbox<?php if (!empty($option_value['image']) && $tbData->OcVersionGte('2.2.0.0')): ?> image<?php endif; ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
          <label<?php if (isset($option['tb_css_classes']) && !empty($option['tb_css_classes']) && $option['tb_css_classes'] == 'style_2'): ?> class="tb_bg_str_2 tb_bg_hover_str_3"<?php endif; ?><?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?> title="<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>"<?php } ?>>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>][]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
            <?php if ($tbData->OcVersionGte('2.2.0.0')): ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['image']) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $option_value['name'] . ($option_value['price'] ? ' ' . $option_value['price_prefix'] . $option_value['price'] : ''); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span>
              <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
              <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?><span>
              (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
              </span><?php } ?>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Please help! I have spend a lot of time to find information about this problem, but unsuccessfully.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to use "select" instead of "checkbox"?

Comment: I need 'multi-select' instead of 'select'.

Comment: Yes, it'll be very nice to have 'select', but with 'multi-select' option